# Is there any performance benefit to keep the values defined in ENUM sorted in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I think the title is pretty self-explanatory. Suppose we have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE tickets (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    priority ENUM('c', 'a', 'b') NOT NULL
);
```

Will it gain any performance if I have the values from the priority ENUM sorted? like so:

```
priority ENUM('a', 'b', 'c') NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are [sorted by their index number](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html#enum-sorting), not their value:

> ENUM values are sorted based on their index numbers, which depend on the order in which the enumeration members were listed in the column specification. For example, 'b' sorts before 'a' for ENUM('b', 'a'). The empty string sorts before nonempty strings, and NULL values sort before all other enumeration values.

So the actual element value has no impact on performance, as MySQL just handles numbers when dealing with [enums](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) (including sorting them):

> The strings you specify as input values are automatically encoded as numbers. See Section 11.7, “Data Type Storage Requirements” for storage requirements for the ENUM type.

While there is no performance benefit, specifying the elements in a properly sorted order (which doesn't necessarily have to be lexigraphically) has the benefit that `order by enum_column` might not give you unexpected results.